# Convert string containing arrays to actual arrays

Tags: javascript

I have no idea why I'm having so much trouble with this. This seems like it should be really simple.

I have a JavaScript string like the following:

`var str = '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]';`

I actually want to convert this into an array of arrays. `str.split(',')` doesn't work because it'll split on the commas in the inner arrays.

I'm sure this conversion is probably something stupidly simple, but I must be missing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string `str` confirms to the JSON spec, so it can be parsed with `JSON.parse`.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]';
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");

console.log(arr[0][0]); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr[0][0][0]); // 1
```

You may use `JSON.parse`, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

https://jsfiddle.net/5yz95ktg/