# JSON array remove Speech mark?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:
          `var array = ['1,2,3']`

How do i remove the: ' from that array  so i get the output `[1,2,3]`

I have tried doing the .replace replace("\''", "") but still get the same output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string containing arrays to actual arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191171/convert-string-containing-arrays-to-actual-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` on array and then `split` on value.

```js
var array = ['1,2,3']
array = [].concat(...array.map(e => e.split(',').map(Number)))
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case you’ve given, with just one string item in the array, it can be boiled down to:

```js
var array = ['1,2,3']
var result = array[0].split(',').map(x => +x)
//                 ^  ^          ^   ^^^^ ^
//                 1  2          3   4    5

console.log(result)
```

1. Take the first (and only) element in the array
2. [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string wherever there’s a comma
3. Use map to apply a function (point 4) to each element that split() returns
4. An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that takes a parameter x and...
5. Coerces x into a number with the [+ operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

If you might have many string items in your array, like:

```
var array = [‘1,2,3’, ‘4,5,6’]
```

then [Nenad’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975448/9409371) answer’s great.